# Is there a way using Dataframes to compare columns and previous and next rows to put a value in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

First off, I have a VERY large dataset (100's of thousands of rows).  There is a column that only has data if an event has started or stopped with no data in between.  I am attempting to fill a new column based on that column depending on whether an event is happening.  I have code currently functioning using iterrows() and dictionaries in if statements, but since my dataset is very large, it is not efficient.

Here is an example of the dataframe I am working with and

| Time | Event | IsEventHappening? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |
| 4 | Event1start |  |
| 5 |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |
| 8 |  |  |
| 9 |  |  |
| 10 |  |  |
| 11 |  |  |
| 12 |  |  |
| 13 | Event2start |  |
| 14 |  |  |
| 15 |  |  |
| 16 | Event1complete |  |
| 17 |  |  |
| 18 |  |  |
| 19 |  |  |
| 20 |  |  |
| 21 |  |  |
| 22 |  |  |
| 23 | Event2complete |  |
| 24 |  |  |
| 25 |  |  |
| 26 |  |  |
| 27 |  |  |
| 28 |  |  |
| 29 |  |  |
| 30 |  |  |

What I would like it to look like after the data manipulation:

| Time | Event | IsEventHappening? | Nicer YetHowMany |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | No | 0 |
| 1 |  | No | 0 |
| 2 |  | No | 0 |
| 3 |  | No | 0 |
| 4 | Event1start | Yes | 1 |
| 5 |  | Yes | 1 |
| 6 |  | Yes | 1 |
| 7 |  | Yes | 1 |
| 8 |  | Yes | 1 |
| 9 |  | Yes | 1 |
| 10 |  | Yes | 1 |
| 11 |  | Yes | 1 |
| 12 |  | Yes | 1 |
| 13 | Event2start | Yes | 2 |
| 14 |  | Yes | 2 |
| 15 |  | Yes | 2 |
| 16 | Event1complete | Yes | 1 |
| 17 |  | Yes | 1 |
| 18 |  | Yes | 1 |
| 19 |  | Yes | 1 |
| 20 |  | Yes | 1 |
| 21 |  | Yes | 1 |
| 22 |  | Yes | 1 |
| 23 | Event2complete | No | 0 |
| 24 |  | No | 0 |
| 25 |  | No | 0 |
| 26 |  | No | 0 |
| 27 |  | No | 0 |
| 28 |  | No | 0 |
| 29 |  | No | 0 |
| 30 |  | No | 0 |

I also want to apologize, I am not sure how to paste in data better than this, it is my first time posting and I come to this amazing website to solve most of my python/panda problems.  I appreciate the support that is given on here and hope that I can find a better solution for my data.

Comment: Create a new column with 1 where `entry` ends with "start", -1 where it ends with "complete", 0 elsewhere. Calculate cumulative sum (`cumsum`) to get the `YetHowMany` column. Where this column is `>0` set `IsEventHappening` to `True`, `False` otherwise.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic solution!!  Shortened my processing time by 30+ minutes!!  Thank you very much!